# React TypeError: cyclic object

Tags: reactjs

I have been having a tough time debugging code for generating React Components. I keep getting a TypeError: cyclic object. I have read up solutions online (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html, [Rendering React Components from Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157286/rendering-react-components-from-array-of-objects)) but still get no display in my code.

Please see below:

```
'use strict'
/**
 * The form input radio button for generating HTML Radio button and Radio     button groups
 */

import React from 'react'
import AbstractFormField from './AbstractFormField.jsx'

const fieldProps = {}
const propsKey = Symbol.for('factorySymbol')

class RadioFactory extends AbstractFormField {
constructor(props) {
    console.log("RadioFactory props: " + JSON.stringify(props))
    super(props) 
    this[propsKey] = Object.assign(fieldProps, props)
    console.log("RadioFactory fieldProps: " + JSON.stringify(this.fieldProps))
    this.validateProps = this.validateProps.bind(this)             
}

get fieldProps() {
    return this[propsKey]
}

get fieldComponent() {
    let validateProps = this.validateProps
    let config = this.fieldProps        
    console.log("getFieldComponent radios: " + JSON.stringify(config.radios))

    let Field = React.createClass({

        render: function () {

            if (!validateProps()) {                    
                 return null                               
            }

            return (
                <div className="radio">{
                    config.radios.map(function(radio, index) {
                                return <label>
                                <input type="radio" value={index} key={"radio_" + index} />{radio}</label>                                    
                            })       
                }<input  type="radio" /></div>
            )
        }
    })

    return <Field {...this.fieldProps} />
}

validateProps() {
    // ensure the propsKey returns a valid config for creating selected form input (radio buttons)
    let config = this.fieldProps
    console.log("config: " + JSON.stringify(config))
    let hasPreField = config.hasOwnProperty("preField") ? true : false
    let hasPostField = config.hasOwnProperty("postField") ? true : false
    let hasAccessory = (config.hasOwnProperty("accessory.pre") ? true : false) || (config.hasOwnProperty("accessory.post") ? true : false) 
    let hasRadios = false        
    let validProps = false

    if(config.hasOwnProperty("type")) {
        validProps = (config.type.code > 0 ) &&             
        ((config.name !== '') || (config.name !== undefined))
        console.log("validProps: " + validProps)
    }

    if(config.hasOwnProperty("radios")) {
        hasRadios = config.radios instanceof Array
        console.log("hasRadios: " + hasRadios)
    }

    return (hasPreField || hasPostField || hasAccessory) || ( validProps && hasRadios )
}
}

class RadioComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

render(){
    console.log("RadioComponent props: " + JSON.stringify(this.props))
    let factory = new RadioFactory(this.props)
    if(factory.validateProps()) {
        return factory.fieldComponent
    } else {
        return null
    }       
}
```

}

export default RadioComponent

Comment: I am not certain how React manages components in loops but if I was to return the values of my radios as strings and not react components, everything works out fine. It seems the problem is in generating the components - causing some cyclic reference to the DOM or radio component and I just can't see why

Comment: Ok, very strange. I have the radio buttons rendered in Chrome but not in Firefox? Any ideas? Thinking my cache or memory leaks in Firefox causing this

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my issue. Turns out that I was referencing an attribute of the configuration (that is, component's props) object which contained the array from which I created the React component in a loop. While in the loop, the configuration is still within the DOM and calling it from within a loop of it's attribute created a "back reference" to the DOM. Two work around: copy the value I needed from the configuration into a temporal value, or update the design having that value within the object I was iterating over. Now, having my React component rendered within the for loop or by map(). This is one case in which SIMPLICITY TRIUMPHED.