# Creating dynamic elements with js array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have and array (JS) of data in React component. I want to generate dynamic divs using loop on that array.

One is it can be done with jquery / javascript

```
componentDidMount(){
    var headingsArray = //contains some data from backend;

    for (var i = 0; i < headingsArray.length; i++) {
        var maprow = '';
        maprow += "<div>"+ headingsArray[i] +"</div>";
       //Some More Data In maprow
       $('.parentDiv').append(maprow);
    }
}

render(){
   return(
       <div className="parentDiv"></div>
   )
}
```

What is the react way to do it? as i am new to react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering React Components from Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157286/rendering-react-components-from-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `array.map` to it:

```
render() {
  const headingsArray = [] // data from your backend

  return (
    <div className="parentDiv">
      {headingsArray.map((heading, index) => <div key={index}>{heading}</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

`key` is a very important prop when mapping through an array. With that, react know which elements have been added, changed or deleted.

In case you have any question regarding `array.map`, please check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) link.

Comment: What is (heading, index) here?

Comment: `heading` is the current element at `index`

Comment: Yes it did, now i am trying to implement it with 2d array. i am gonna accept this as an answer. thankyou :)

Comment: How do i map [This Kind of Array](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/payroll-plus-finja1.appspot.com/o/payrollcdn%2FScreen%20Shot%202017-09-19%20at%205.40.46%20PM.png?alt=media&token=8610a94d-4825-46cb-b7b2-bf1a10fe54a8)

Comment: It looks an `object` rather than an array

Comment: so how do i do that? can you please help me out?

Comment: `Object.keys(yourObject).map(key => console.log(key, yourObject[key]))`