# How can I render the array containing object in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

How can I render the name and models of the array containing objects . there are two properties inside each object .. 
1.Name
2.models (array containing objects)
How can I render both ? or just the models

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
models: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
name: "Animals"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering React Components from Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157286/rendering-react-components-from-array-of-objects)

Comment: Just map over all the models whilst passing down the name as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

I got it using React fragments

```
data.map(({ name, models }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div>Name: { name }</div>
        {
          models.map(model => (
            <div>{ model }</div>
          ))
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    ))
```