# In React, how to get state into the UI, and then map through the array object

Tags: reactjs, state

I am building a grid order tool for product display on a website. It takes in a CSV, parses it into JSON, *allows the user to reorder it*, and then saves the new CSV. Because I am saving the array object in state, I have two problems in one. After uploading a file, I managed to get the array object into state. There are two parts to this question.

1) How do I get state into the UI? 
2) Then I will have to map through an array of objects

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import Papa from 'papaparse'

    class Product extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {data: [] };   
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this)
        }

        handleChange(event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            const inventory = event.target.files[0]
            Papa.parse(inventory, {
                header: true,
                complete: this.updateData
            })
        } // END

        updateData(results) {
            const data = results.data
            console.log(data)
            this.setState({data}) // I have it in state. How to get it in UI?
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <form >
                        <label>
                            Upload file:
                            <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                    </form>

                    <div> Map through state here </div> 
                </div>          
            );
        }

    } // END

    export default Product
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering React Components from Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157286/rendering-react-components-from-array-of-objects)

Comment: there are many, many other examples on Stack Overflow about how to use React to render data on screen.  Have you searched for those examples and followed the answers provided?  if so, in what way were they inadequate?

Comment: Yes. I am still reading those and will update my ticket to be as precise and informative as possible. Thank you.

Comment: The possible duplicate above is very helpful in explaining how to map over an array object. The answer to this question includes how to render state in the dom, which is a different issue not addressed in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method that maps your collection and returns an array of UI components. Then render them in your component's return statement.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Papa from 'papaparse'

class Product extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: [] };   
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
        this.renderData = this.renderData.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const inventory = event.target.files[0]
        Papa.parse(inventory, {
            header: true,
            complete: this.updateData
        })
    } // END

    updateData(results) {
        const data = results.data
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({data}) // I have it in state. How to get it in UI?
    }

    // method that check data prop in state for items in array, 
    // returning a collection of UI components if there is, 
    // otherwise returns null
    renderData() {
        return this.state.data.length > 1 
            ? this.state.data.map((item) => (
                <div>{item.title}</div> // assuming your data item has a title prop
            )) 
            : null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form >
                    <label>
                        Upload file:
                        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </label>
                </form>

                <div> 
                    {/* execute method here */}
                    {this.renderData()} 
                </div> 
            </div>          
        );
    }

} // END

export default Product
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed. I can now render state in the UI and map over the array object.