# How can I render several objects of the same class in React? (like Instagram, Facebook or Pinterest)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, render

Basically I want to show a component (**card**) that shows a product, but several times. The component takes the data from a database, so I only need to render the `<Product />` component with different `props`. In the next image's the complete render as it should be. What I need to do is that each card extracts the data by going through the database and renders a certain amount of **cards** as it scrolls (for example, when it is scrolled on the main IG page and more publications are appearing)

--> IMAGE Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXv4V.jpg

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter and need to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering React Components from Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157286/rendering-react-components-from-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display your card with variable data in a constant and then pass props to it.

For example

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/z340z2zl3m)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Card } from "antd";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const card = prop => (
    <div style={{ background: "#ECECEC", padding: "30px" }}>
      <Card title="Card title" bordered={true} style={{ width: 300 }}>
        <p>{prop.title}</p>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {card({ title: "Facebook" })}
      {card({ title: "Twitter" })}
      {card({ title: "Instagram" })}
      {card({ title: "YouTube" })}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```