# Dynamic react-bootstrap carousel breaking apart. (A valid React element (or null) must be returned.)

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I will try and explain best I can. 
I want to create a `Carousel` dynamically.
This is the representation of my data going into making this happen.

Below is a `question array`. This is represented by a question with (in this case ) four answers to choose from in the `question_list_items`.

```
    let question = [{ id: 52, question: "I still enjoy the things I used to", type: "Text list",
        question_list_items: Array(4)
        0: {id: 164, list_item: "Definitely as much", item_value: "0", sort_order: 4, question_id: 52, …}
        1: {id: 165, list_item: "Not quite so much", item_value: "1", sort_order: 3, question_id: 52, …}
        2: {id: 166, list_item: "Only a little", item_value: "2", sort_order: 2, question_id: 52, …}
        3: {id: 167, list_item: "Not at all", item_value: "3", sort_order: 1, question_id: 52, …}
    ];
```

**Main render**
Here is the start of the Carousel component. I start with the header section and call the `<Questionnaire/>` component to fill in the body.

```
return (
    <Carousel
        activeIndex={index}
        direction={direction}
        onSelect={(i,e)=>this.handleSelect(i,e)}
    >

       <Questionnaire/>

    </Carousel>
);
```

**Questionnaire Component**
It is here where I think it goes wrong.
Here I loop over all the questions inside `this.props.questions`.
I check the `Type` of the question to render the correct type question.
This is done with the help of a `switch`. In this case Im only showing the `<TextList />` component.

```
const Questionnaire = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    this.props.questions.map((row, index) => {
        let element;
        switch (row.type) {
            case "Text list":
                element = <TextList key={`questionList-${index}`} index={index} row={row} />;
                break;
        }
        return element;
    })
});
```

**TextList Component**

In this component is where I build a single slide of the carousel.
This component Calls the `<TextListButton />` component to render the answer options for the current question.

```
const TextList = SortableElement(({row}) => {
    console.log("row",row);
    return (
    // ******************************************************************************************************
    // ************************************      LIST TYPE QUESTION     *************************************
    // ******************************************************************************************************
        <Carousel.Item  style={{"padding": "0 20px 0 20px", height: "600px", width: "1024px", textAlign: "center"}}>
            <h3>{row.question}</h3>
            <div style={{ paddingTop: "40px" }}>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={3} />
                    <Col xs={6}>
                        <div>
                            <ButtonGroup vertical block>
                                {row.question_list_items.map((row, idx) => {
                                    return <TextListButton key={`buttonList-${idx}`} index={idx} row={row} />;
                                })}
                            </ButtonGroup>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={3} />
                </Row>
            </div>

            <Carousel.Caption>
                <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
    );
});
```

**TextListButton Component**
This creates each answer item to choose from.

```
const TextListButton = SortableElement(({row}) => {
    console.log("item row",row);
    return (
        <Button>{row.list_item}</Button>
    );
});
```

**NOTE on Questionnaire Component**

I have tried to wrap the `Questionnaire` component in `<div>` tags. This makes it render, but its not a carousel anymore, its just one long list of questions and answers. Im not sure how to approach this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
const Questionnaire = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    return (
        <div>  <=********************************************HERE
        {this.props.questions.map((row, index) => {
            let element;
            switch (row.type) {
                case "Text list":
                    element = <TextList key={`questionList-${index}`} index={index} row={row} />;
                    break;

            }
            return element;
        })}
        </div>  <=********************************************HERE
    );
});
```

**Update on declaring `let element = null;`**

It seems to run for 14 questions, but then fails. ( there is only 14 questions )

[image]

**STACT TRACE**

[image]

Comment: initialize element with null  `let element = null;`. If your switch dont match the defined case then you are returning `undefined` thus the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined `let element;` its initialized as `undefined` in Javascript and 
if your switch dont match the defined case (in your example `Text list`) then you are returning `undefined` thus the error.

On side note since you only have one condition you dont need switch/case you are better of with if statement unless the example in question was trimmed down version.

Since you are using React 15.x you cannot leave child orphan, thus you need to wrap your array in a div or some other html element:  [Rendering React Components from Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157286/rendering-react-components-from-array-of-objects)

Your first issue was you were rendering undefined in array which is not allowed, thus you can define `element = null`

```
const Questionnaire = SortableContainer(({items}) => {
    return (
        <div>  <=******************************************** You can remove this if you want or replace it with empty <> fragment
        {this.props.questions.map((row, index) => {
            let element = null; <=********************************************HERE
            switch (row.type) {
                case "Text list":
                    element = <TextList key={`questionList-${index}`} index={index} row={row} />;
                    break;

            }
            return element;
        })}
        </div>
    );
});
```

Your second issue is with rendering array list without wrapping in a HTML element. You would have to restructure your code so that its not returning array child elements without a parent container.

One possible way is you can try to update your Carousel direct as below:

```
<Carousel
activeIndex={index}
direction={direction}
onSelect={(i,e)=>this.handleSelect(i,e)}
>
  {this.props.questions.filter(question => question.type === "Text list")
    .map((row, index) => 
    <Carousel.Item>
      <Questionnaire question={row.question} answers={row.question_list_items} />
    </Carousel.Item>
    )
  }
</Carousel>
```

And Questionnaire can act as dumb component which only renders question/answers

Comment: I have tried it and it returns 14 elements, which is the amount of questions ( correct) but it fails directly after that. Will update my question.

Comment: Can you post stack trace of that, that will give you idea of where additional error is happening

Comment: do I do `console.trace();` just before `return element`?

Comment: No just click on the little arrow icon right next to `Warning` that will give you stack trace and then you can copy that and post it here.

Comment: Just posted. Is there any way to start a private chat in Stackoverflow?

Comment: Its giving stack trace of mostly React's code which aint useful in diagnosing which part of your code caused it. In that stack trace once you go deep down, ignoring all react code traces, you should start seeing your code base which triggered the error, you can diagnose it that way or by placing console.log in your code and identify which one did not run properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198884/discussion-between-morne-and-rikin).