# How can I display a set of array on click of a button from it's child component using React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How can I display a set of array on click of a button from it's child component using React?

Since I am new to React, I have been struggling to show a text not alert or else. Below is the code I have written so far.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import LandingComponent from './LandingComponent'

class EmployeeList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
         Employee : [
             {
                 ID: 1,
                 FirstName: 'Nancy',
                 LastName: 'Davolio',
                 Address: '507',
                 City: 'Seattle,WA',
                 PostalCode: '98122',
                 COuntry: 'USA'
             },
             {
                ID: 2,
                FirstName: 'Margaret',
                LastName: 'Peacock',
                Address: '507',
                City: 'Seattle,WA',
                PostalCode: '98122',
                COuntry: 'USA'
            }]}
            }
              showEmpList() {
              return {Employee: this.state.Employee}
}
             render() {
             return (
             <div>      
             <LandingComponent ListHandler={this.showEmpList}/>
            </div>
            )
       }
     }
                 export default EmployeeList
```

And my child component which has a button on click of it I want to display result.

```
                 import React from 'react'

                 function LandingComponent(props) {
                   return (
                     <div>
                     <button>Display Not Found</button>
                     <button onClick={props.ListHandler}>Show Employee List</button>
                     </div>
                      )
                      }

                       export default LandingComponent
```

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32157286/10349960) should help you.

Comment: No, it's not relevant to what I asked for.

Comment: I tried this way but it doesn't render anything on UI on the other hand console.log gives me the desired result. So plz tell me how to show the same output on UI?? 
showEmpList(){
     console.log(this.state.Employee)   
     return (<div>{this.state.Employee}</div>)
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a variable to state indicating whether or not to show emloyee list:

```
this.state = {
    ...
    showEmployeeList: false
}
```

Declare a function that will switch the `showEmployeeList`:

```
showEmpList () {
    this.setState({
        showEmloyeesList: !this.state.showEmployeesList,
    })
}
```

Write a function that will render employees:

```
renderEmloyees (employees) {
    return (
        <div>
          {employees.map(e => (
            <div key=e.ID>
              {e.FirstName}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
  )
}
```

If `showEmployeeList` is `true`, render employees:

```
<LandingComponent ListHandler={this.showEmpList}/>
{this.state.showEmployeeList && renderEmployees(this.state.Employee)}
```