# A javascript reactjs question about props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the simple App.js code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Member from './Member'

function App () {
  const members = [
    { name: 'Andy', age: 22 },
    { name: 'Bruce', age: 33 },
    { name: 'Mary', age: 11 }
  ]
  for (const member of members) {
    return <Member {...member} />
  }
}

export default App
```

Here is the Member.js:

```
import React from 'react'

function Member ({ name, age }) {
  return (
  <div>
    {name}
    <hr />
    {age}
  </div>)
}

export default Member
```

The problem is only the first object `{name:'Andy', age: 22}` shows in the browser. How can I change the code to show all three of them? 
I am new to Javascript and React. I just can't figure it out. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because as soon as the first iteration is initiated you are returning the `jsx` and thus it shows only the first member.

Here how you can loop on all members

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {members.map(member => <Member key={member.name} {...member} /> )}
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please bear in mind that the other answers use member name as the key which is poor practice. Imagine if you had two members with the same name, then you'd get the duplicate key error.

Try:

```
import React from 'react'
import Member from './Member'


function App () {

  const members = [
    { name: 'Andy', age: 22 },
    { name: 'Bruce', age: 33 },
    { name: 'Mary', age: 11 }
  ]

  return  (
    members.map((member, index) => (
      <Member key={`${member.name}${index}`} {...member} />
    ))
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call `return`, it will exit the function and return the result of the expression beside the `return` keyword. Even though you are returning within a `for` loop, your code will return the value immediately from the function.

If instead you want to return an array of items, you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this:

```js
function App () {
  const members = [
    { name: 'Andy', age: 22 },
    { name: 'Bruce', age: 33 },
    { name: 'Mary', age: 11 }
  ];
  return {members.map((member, index) => <Member key={index} {...member} />)};
}
```

`map` allows you to execute a function over every element in an array, and then return that modified array. When creating a collection of elements, they each need a unique (unique to the collection) `key` attribute. I am using the index of the item in the array here.

Comment: Hey Billy, we can also return the array of elements, check Ayudh answer

Comment: @YashJoshi You can return an array of elements, but then you won't be able to render them directly to the (virtual) DOM. React components may only return a single React element. So a [fragment can then be used to group and return multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32157488/1406083).

Comment: Did not understood it properly what do you mean by not render to Virtual DOM. Check this Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-carson-5l7r8  You can see that we have all Member Component showing up.

Comment: @YashJoshi ooh that must be new since the last time I used React. Thanks for the heads-up; I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Glad my comment helped :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is not to spread the  props at first

Pass the array as it is as

Then in the Member component; use the .map() function to iterate over the Member props like member.map(user => {user.name}, {user.age} )

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation