# render MUI components from an array of data and display the first one differently

Tags: reactjs, typescript, foreach, material-ui, accordion

Here I am trying to render the contents of `Accordion` through a list array passing down the props to a component. I kind of understand where the issue is but I don't know how else I can call the component and pass the props. Below is my code.

Code of the parent component

```
const Sandbox = () => {

let summaryContents: any[] = [
    {
      Title: "Construction costs",
      TotalPrice: "$25000",
      Subcontents: [
        {
          Subtitle: "Sanitation",
          SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
        },
        {
          Subtitle: "PoolLights",
          SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
        },
        {
          Subtitle: "PoolCleaner",
          SubtitlePrice: "$15000",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      Title: "Pool interior costs",
      TotalPrice: "$20000",
      Subcontents: [
        {
          Subtitle: "Title1",
          SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
        },
        {
          Subtitle: "Title2",
          SubtitlePrice: "$10000",
        },
        {
          Subtitle: "Title3",
          SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
        },
      ],
    },
];


  let summaryContentsList: any[] = [];

  summaryContents.forEach((item: any, index: number) => {
    summaryContentsList.push(
      <QuoteSummary
        
        Title={item.Title}
        TotalPrice={item.TotalPrice}
        Subtitle={item.Subcontents.Subtitle}
        SubtitlePrice={item.Subcontents.SubtitlePrice}
      />
    );
  });
  return (
    <>
      
      {summaryContentsList}
    </>
  );
};
```

Code for the child component

```
const QuoteSummary: FC<QuoteSummaryProps> = (props: QuoteSummaryProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <QuoteCard>
      <Typography variant="h1" sx={{ paddingBottom: 2 }}>
        Quote Summary
      </Typography>
      <DialogCloseButton onClose={clicked} />

      <Accordion
        className={classes.accordion}
        sx={{
          paddingTop: 0,
        }}
      >
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography variant="h3">{props.Title}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="h3" sx={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
            {props.TotalPrice}
          </Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>{props.Subtitle}</Typography>
          <Typography>{props.SubtitlePrice}</Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </QuoteCard>
  );
};
```

[image]

This is how it looks where as I wanted to render the Title only once and accordion contents below.
What would be the approach I will have to follow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering React Components from Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157286/rendering-react-components-from-array-of-objects)

Comment: The logic is there but the problem is I'm rendering it through a component so I'm passing props for the parent component to child component. So that link you've provided doesnt solve it @wowandy

Comment: @kevinTHEprogrammer I don't understand your request. Do you want the title `Quote Summary` only appear once? then why don't you put it outside?

Comment: @NearHuscarl I'm rendering <QuoteSummary/> component in the parent component <Sandbox/>. The Quote Summary Title is inside of <QuoteSummary/> component. Don't know how should I take it out of the loop when passing the entire <QuoteSummary/> component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `QuoteCard` outside and only place `Accordion` item in the child component:

```
const QuoteSummary: FC<QuoteSummaryProps> = (props: QuoteSummaryProps) => {
  return (
    <Accordion>
      {...}
    </Accordion>
  );
};
```

```
<QuoteCard>
  <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ paddingBottom: 2 }}>
    Quote Summary
  </Typography>
  <DialogCloseButton onClose={() => {}} />

  {summaryContents.map((item) => (
    <QuoteSummary
      Title={item.Title}
      TotalPrice={item.TotalPrice}
      Subtitle={item.Subcontents.Subtitle}
      SubtitlePrice={item.Subcontents.SubtitlePrice}
    />
  ))}
</QuoteCard>
```

**EDIT:** Another approach is to render the title conditionally in the child component based on the props provided from the parent:

```
const QuoteSummary: FC<QuoteSummaryProps> = (props: QuoteSummaryProps) => {
  return (
    <QuoteCard>
      {props.displayTitle && (
        <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ paddingBottom: 2 }}>
          Quote Summary
        </Typography>
      )}
      <DialogCloseButton onClose={() => {}} />
      <Accordion>
        {...}
      </Accordion>
    </QuoteCard>
  );
};
```

```
<>
  {summaryContents.map((item, i) => (
    <QuoteSummary
      displayTitle={i === 0}
      Title={item.Title}
      TotalPrice={item.TotalPrice}
      Subtitle={item.Subcontents.Subtitle}
      SubtitlePrice={item.Subcontents.SubtitlePrice}
    />
  ))}
</>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Its working and I already know this but I wanted this to be inside a component? Is there any other we can do it ? @NearHuscarl

Comment: If not its alright just needed to know if theres any other way

Comment: @kevinTHEprogrammer Why do you want it to be inside the component though? Do you have other components in play?

Comment: well should set up this child component so then it could be reused throughout the project or where ever the this child component is being used will have to come up with Quote Summary title in the parent component

Comment: @kevinTHEprogrammer see my updated answer.

Comment: needed lil help over here too if you can help me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69656354/passing-props-to-a-component-from-nested-array-in-react

Answer (score 0):

You can create a render function for array items and use them like this:

```jsx
const Sandbox = () => {
  const summaryContents: any[] = [
    {
      Title: "Construction costs",
      TotalPrice: "$25000",
      Subcontents: [{
          Subtitle: "Sanitation",
          SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
        },
        {
          Subtitle: "PoolLights",
          SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
        },
        {
          Subtitle: "PoolCleaner",
          SubtitlePrice: "$15000",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      Title: "Pool interior costs",
      TotalPrice: "$20000",
      Subcontents: [{
          Subtitle: "Title1",
          SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
        },
        {
          Subtitle: "Title2",
          SubtitlePrice: "$10000",
        },
        {
          Subtitle: "Title3",
          SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const renderContent = (item: any) => (
     <QuoteSummary
        Title={item.Title}
        TotalPrice={item.TotalPrice}
        Subtitle={item.Subcontents.Subtitle}
        SubtitlePrice={item.Subcontents.SubtitlePrice}
      />
  );

  return (
    <>
      {summaryContents.map(renderContent)}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it didn't actually work. Here you have done exactly the same what I have done using array.map whereas I have done it using arrayList and a foreach Loop. The issue here is the title 'Quote Summary' is part of the  child component. So I will have to pass only the accordion content in array. not sure how I do that if I have to pass the props?