# Passing props to a component from nested array in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, multidimensional-array, foreach, react-props

I have a nested array like below. Accordion should be displayed according to the no. of array I have and the accordion summary would contain the details 'Title' , 'TotalPrice'. Whereas accordion details would contain the 'subcontents', 'Subtitle' and 'SubtitlePrice'.

```
let summaryContents: any[] = [
{
  Title: "Construction costs",
  TotalPrice: "$25000",
  Subcontents: [
    {
      Subtitle: "Sanitation",
      SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
    },
    {
      Subtitle: "PoolLights",
      SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
    },
    {
      Subtitle: "PoolCleaner",
      SubtitlePrice: "$15000",
    },
  ],
},
{
  Title: "Pool interior costs",
  TotalPrice: "$20000",
  Subcontents: [
    {
      Subtitle: "Title1",
      SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
    },
    {
      Subtitle: "Title2",
      SubtitlePrice: "$10000",
    },
    {
      Subtitle: "Title3",
      SubtitlePrice: "$5000",
    },
  ],
}
```

I will have to make pass these values as props to another component. If it is within the component I know we can do something like this

```
return (
<>
  {summaryContents.map((item: any) => {
    <>
      {item.Title}
      {item.TotalPrice}

      {typeof item.Subcontents == "object" ? (
        <>
          {item.Subcontents.map((subItem: any) => (
            <>
              {subItem.Subtitle}
              {subItem.SubtitlePrice}
              
            </>
          ))}
        </>
      ) : null}
</>;
  })}

</>


 );
```

What can we do to pass it another component like the one given below

```
<QuoteSummary
  Title={item.Title}
  TotalPrice={item.TotalPrice}
  Subtitle={item.Subcontents.Subtitle}
  SubtitlePrice={item.Subcontents.SubtitlePrice}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this might help you.

```
// your parent component
  return (
    <>
      {summaryContents.map((item: any) => {
        return <QuoteSummary
          Title={item.Title}
          TotalPrice={item.TotalPrice}
          Subcontents={item.Subcontents}
        />
      })}
    </>
  );

// Your child1 component
const QuoteSummary = ({ Title, TotalPrice, Subcontents }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {Title}
      {TotalPrice}
      {Subcontents.map((item: any) => {
        return <SubContent
          Subtitle={item.Subtitle}
          SubtitlePrice={item.SubtitlePrice}
        />
      })}
    </>
  );
}

// Your child2 component 
const SubContent = ({ Subtitle, SubtitlePrice }) => {
  return <>
    {Subtitle}
    {SubtitlePrice}
  </>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but here I shouldn't be changing the props passed through the component that is props passed through component should be as following 
Title
  TotalPrice
  Subtitle
  SubtitlePrice