# React: render each component in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, syntax

In my application, I want the React MUI library component, `AccordionDetails` to display each element in array `targetTypeData` (the length of the array is *currently* always 6).
The array contains a `Typography` component.

My current solution properly displays the data has limitations and is not concise. Is there another way to render each element in an array?

```
  var targetTypeData = [];
          for(let i=0; i<targetTypes.length;i++){
            targetTypeData.push(
              <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} 
              color= {"white" } >
              {`${targetTypes[i].toString()} : ${targetNumberData[i].toString()}`}
            </Typography> 
            )
          }

   //more code
          <AccordionDetails>
              <Typography>
                {targetTypeData[0]}
                {targetTypeData[1]}
                {targetTypeData[2]}
                {targetTypeData[3]}
                {targetTypeData[4]}
                {targetTypeData[5]}

              </Typography>

            
        </AccordionDetails>
```

Comment: I think it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157286/rendering-react-components-from-array-of-objects

Answer (score -1):

(Edited) Try this:

```
      var targetTypeData = [];
      for(let i=0; i<targetTypes.length;i++){
        targetTypeData.push(
          `${targetTypes[i].toString()} : ${targetNumberData[i].toString()}` 
        )
      }
      // more code
      <AccordionDetails>
            {targetTypeData.map((item) => (
               <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color= {"white"} >
                   {item}
               </Typography> 
            ))}
      </AccordionDetails>
```

Comment: this did not render anything.

Comment: Your `.map` isn't correct.  `item` is already ``${targetTypes[i].toString()} : ${targetNumberData[i].toString()}``

Comment: My bad, I wasn't paying enough attention. I fixed it

Comment: Better, now you might consider just doing the transformation of the data right in the JSX mapping.  No need to create a separate array and a second loop!